# How to open appication from taskbar with VBA?

Tags: vba

I found a code online:

```
Public Sub showProcesses()
    Dim W As Object
    Dim ProcessQuery As String
    Dim processes As Object
    Dim process As Object
    Set W = GetObject("winmgmts:")
    ProcessQuery = "SELECT * FROM win32_process"
    Set processes = W.execquery(ProcessQuery)
    For Each process In processes
        MsgBox process.Name
        MsgBox process.Description
    Next
    Set W = Nothing
    Set processes = Nothing
    Set process = Nothing
End Sub
```

It prints out the name and description of all active processes.

Example:

> TeraPad.exe
>  acad.exe
>  WINWORD.EXE
>  EXCEL.EXE
>  ...

With the code below I got the window names of the applications that are available in the Taskbar:

```
Private Sub AppActivates(WindowName As String)

    Dim WD, task, n As Long
    Set WD = CreateObject("Word.Application")

    For Each task In WD.Tasks
        MsgBox task.Name
    Next

    WD.Quit
    Set WD = Nothing

End Sub
```

Example:

> Basic_vba.pdf - Adobe Acrobat Reader DC
>  AutoCAD Mechanical 2016 -  [sample_model.dwg]
>  20170424.txt - TeraPad
>  ...

The application acad.exe [AutoCAD] is in the taskbar(status is Minimum), I want to open(call) it's windows up in VBA.

Is that possible?

Any tips on these will be great help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `AppActivate` method along with the window title (which just happens to be the name of the task).

```
VBA.AppActivate("Basic_vba.pdf - Adobe Acrobat Reader DC")
```

If the window is minimized, then you'll need to send a message to the window to restore or maximize it.

Comment: "If the window is minimized, then you'll need to send a message to the window to restore or maximize it." <= This is exactly what I want to ask :(, can you guide me how to do it ?

Comment: You need to use the [SetWindowLong](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633591(v=vs.85).aspx) API function, along with the correct style for maximized.